# Firebase firestore is not accepting or showing any data on the console

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am starting to work with firebase firestore in combination with an Android/Java project. I have connected my project to Firestore and added cloud firestore as well. I am in the stage of adding data to the firestore database from the emulator's UI. The java code I'm using is supposed to show a Toast indicating if the data is saved successfully or show a Toast if failed.

```
db.collection("TEST").add(test).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

The problem is when I enter information in the EditText views and hit the button, the data doesn't get saved to the database and the firestore console doesn't show anything no matter how I try to refresh the page. I have been searching for two days now but no luck at all. Please help me I'm stuck.

I will include the code of java and XML layout even though I don't think the problem is the code since it's so simple.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/surname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Surname"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="OK"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/age" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surname" />
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText user_name, user_surname, user_age;
Button okBtn;
FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    user_name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    user_surname = findViewById(R.id.surname);
    user_age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    okBtn = findViewById(R.id.ok);
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String Name = user_name.getText().toString();
            String Surname = user_surname.getText().toString();
            String Age = user_age.getText().toString();

            Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<>();
            test.put("name", Name);
            test.put("surname", Surname);
            test.put("age", Age);

            db.collection("TEST").add(test).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Is any of the toast messages displayed?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But I tried to connect to firebase using my friend's pc and it's working completely fine. I think the problem is with my laptop or Android Studio configurations I made when I firstly installed it

Comment: Should I reinstall Android Studio and try to go with the default configurations as possible as I can?

Comment: I'm not sure about Android Studio. Be sure to have an internet connection.